# How do I run my cucumber-jvm features in parallel? (with maven using cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin)

Tags: maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

I am trying to incorporate a maven plugin [cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin](https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin) into my **Cucumber-JVM** code and am running into some problems... I think I have configured my `pom.xml` properly, but my cucumber **features are still getting ran one by one instead of in parallel**.

**How do I configure my pom.xml to make my cucumber features run in parallel?** I have some feature files that block execution and I don't want to have to wait for them to finish in order to start testing the other features.

I followed two tutorials, and can't find where I am going wrong, or if this is expected:

- https://opencredo.com/test-automation-concepts-parallel-test-execution/
- http://automationrhapsody.com/running-cucumber-tests-in-parallel/

## Structure

Here's my program's structure:

```
├── features/
│   └── api/
│       ├── 006-Email.feature
│       └── 999-Login.feature
├── results/
│   └── api-json.json
└── src/
    └── java/
        ├── pom.xml
        ├── src/
        │   └── test/
        │       └── java/
        │           └── com/
        │               └── mycompany/
        │                   └── commonapps/
        │                       └── queuemanager/
        │                           ├── Globals.java
        │                           ├── GmailHelper.java
        │                           ├── HttpDeleteWithBody.java
        │                           ├── JsonHelper.java
        │                           ├── RequestHelper.java
        │                           ├── RunApiTest.java
        │                           ├── ThreadedSteps.java
        │                           └── UserHelper.java
        └── steps/
            └── com/
                └── mycompany/
                    └── commonapps/
                        └── queuemanager/
                            ├── GivenSteps.java
                            ├── Setup.java
                            ├── ThenSteps.java
                            └── WhenSteps.java
```

## Maven Pom Logic

The way I configured my pom is as follows:

1. I copy `../../features/api/` to my build path using [Maven Resources Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html)

   ```
   <build>
     <resources>
        <resource>
           <directory>../../features/api/</directory> 
        </resource>
     </resources>
   </build>
   ```
2. I tell [cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin](https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin) that my `features` are now located at `target/classes/active/`, because I think `../../features/api/` was copied to `target/`, so `target/active/` should contain my `.feature` files.. I think.

   ```
    <plugin>
         <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
         <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
         ...
         <configuration>
             ...
             <featuresDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/active/</featuresDirectory>
             ...
         </configuration>
    </plugin>
   ```
3. Then, after I run `maven test`, all `.feature` files are then compiled into `target/test-classes/Parallel**IT.class`. One per feature file.
4. So I tell [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html) to run all `<include>**/Parallel*IT.class</include>` files in parallel, which are the feature files created by cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin.

   ```
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <executions>
          <execution>
             <id>acceptance-test</id>
             <phase>integration-test</phase>
             <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
               <forkCount>5</forkCount>
               <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
               <includes>
                 <include>**/Parallel*IT.class</include>
               </includes>
             </configuration>
          </execution>
       </executions>
    </plugin>
   ```

## Full pom.xml

And my pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.mycompany.commonapps</groupId>
   <artifactId>e2e-server</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <dependencies>
     ...
   </dependencies>
   <build>
<!-- COPY RESOURCES TO TARGET/ -->
      <resources>
    <!-- copies features to target: "${project.build.directory}/classes/active/" -->
         <resource>
            <directory>../../features/api/</directory> 
         </resource>
      </resources>
<!-- RUN EACH CUCUMBER FEATURE FILE AS A FORK -->
      <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>generateRunners</id>
          <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
          <goals>
        <goal>generateRunners</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
          <glue>com.mycompany.commonapps.queuemanager</glue>
           <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources</outputDirectory>
           <featuresDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/active/</featuresDirectory>
           <cucumberOutputDir>${project.build.directory}</cucumberOutputDir>
           <format>json</format>
           <!--<strict>true</strict>
           <monochrome>true</monochrome> 
           <useTestNG>false</useTestNG>
           <namingScheme>simple</namingScheme>-->
           <parallelScheme>FEATURE</parallelScheme>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<!-- RUN ALL CLASSES CREATED BY cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin IN PARALLEL -->
        <executions>
         <execution>
             <id>acceptance-test</id>
             <phase>integration-test</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>test</goal>
             </goals>
             <configuration>
                 <forkCount>5</forkCount>
                 <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                 <includes>
                    <include>**/Parallel*IT.class</include>
                 </includes>
             </configuration>
        </execution>
        </executions>
         </plugin>
<!-- ADD ../../STEPS/ TO THE SOURCE -->
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>add-source</id>
                  <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>add-source</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <sources>
                        <source>steps/</source>
                        <source>src/test/java/</source>
                     </sources>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

## Cucumber Runner

And my cucumber running class looks like this:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin={"pretty","json:../../results/api-json.json"}, glue={"com.mycompany.commonapps.queuemanager"}, features={"../../features/api/active"})
public class RunApiTest {
}
```

## Output

When I run `mvn test`, I get the following:

```
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building e2e  Server Tests 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2 has been relocated to commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:add-source (add-source) @ e2e--server ---
[INFO] Source directory: /media/ifc-dev-1/ESD-ISO/e2e-/src/java/steps added.
[INFO] Source directory: /media/ifc-dev-1/ESD-ISO/e2e-/src/java/src/test/java added.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ e2e--server ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 7 resources
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] Copying 7 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ e2e--server ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 12 source files to /media/ifc-dev-1/ESD-ISO/e2e-/src/java/target/classes
[INFO] /media/ifc-dev-1/ESD-ISO/e2e-/src/java/src/test/java/com/mycompany/commonapps/queuemanager/GmailHelper.java: /media/ifc-dev-1/ESD-ISO/e2e-/src/java/src/test/java/com/mycompany/commonapps/queuemanager/GmailHelper.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /media/ifc-dev-1/ESD-ISO/e2e-/src/java/src/test/java/com/mycompany/commonapps/queuemanager/GmailHelper.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin:1.2.1:generateRunners (generateRunners) @ e2e--server ---
[INFO] Adding /media/ifc-dev-1/ESD-ISO/e2e-/src/java/target/generated-test-sources to test-compile source root
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ e2e--server ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /media/ifc-dev-1/ESD-ISO/e2e-/src/java/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ e2e--server ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 10 source files to /media/ifc-dev-1/ESD-ISO/e2e-/src/java/target/test-classes
[INFO] /media/ifc-dev-1/ESD-ISO/e2e-/src/java/src/test/java/com/mycompany/commonapps/queuemanager/GmailHelper.java: /media/ifc-dev-1/ESD-ISO/e2e-/src/java/src/test/java/com/mycompany/commonapps/queuemanager/GmailHelper.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /media/ifc-dev-1/ESD-ISO/e2e-/src/java/src/test/java/com/mycompany/commonapps/queuemanager/GmailHelper.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ e2e--server ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /media/ifc-dev-1/ESD-ISO/e2e-/src/java/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.mycompany.commonapps.queuemanager.RunApiTest
....
*Tests run one by one properly*
...
Tests run: 31, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:40 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-10T15:49:11-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/261M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project e2e--server: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /media/ifc-dev-1/ESD-ISO/e2e-/src/java/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Does anyone see what I did wrong?

---

## More Debugging Info

- cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin's `outputDirectory` *is* getting created **correctly** and contains a bunch of Parallel**IT.class files
- cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin's `featuresDirectory` *is* getting accessed **correctly**.
- cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin's **`cucumberOutputDir`** ***is NOT* getting created at all** after a build.

Comment: I would suggest that you run Maven using the -X and perhaps -e options to get more information from your build. Do a mvn -h to get all options available. It is also worth noting that Cucumber is not thread safe and does not support parallelism. You scenarios may or may not work when they are executed in parallel.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasSundberg, I'll try that

Comment: i would suggest to take a look [QAF Gherkin Scenario Factory](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html)

Comment: Please clarify what do you want to use cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin first place ? Why don't you just use maven-failsafe-plugin to run each of the .feature files in parallel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work! Here's what I had to do to make my tests run in parallel:

1. I move some fields in the `maven-surefire-plugin` `execution` tag to the `configuration` tag. I *moved* this section:

   ```xml
        <forkCount>5</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
        <includes>
           <include>**/*IT.class</include>
        </includes>
   ```

   - So that my `maven-surefire-plugin` now looks like this:

   ```
       <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.19.1</version>

         <configuration>
            <forkCount>5</forkCount>
            <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*IT.class</include>
            </includes>
         </configuration>

       </plugin>
   ```
2. Since `cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin` is now running the show, I had to **remove my cucumber runner class**. I commented it out like this:

```java
    /*
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(plugin={"pretty","json:../../results/api-json.json"}, glue={"com.mycompany.commonapps.queuemanager"}, features={"../../features/api/active"})
    */
    public class RunApiTest {
    }
```

And that's it. Since `Parallel**IT.class` where getting created, it was `maven-surefire-plugin` that was not working right.

Comment: can you please clarify https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45436476/parallel-execution-of-features-files-maven-failsafe-plugin-vs-cucumber-jvm-par

Comment: Hey Katie, how can I let the runner run the show and still have everything run in parallel? If we can't, which limitation is stopping us to do so.