# Parallel execution of features files : maven-failsafe-plugin vs cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin

Tags: selenium, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, maven-failsafe-plugin

Currently I'm using maven-failsafe-plugin to run multiple feature files in parallel with Selenium Grid + nodes ( all running in docker containers )

I'm basic questions as below

1. when to use cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin ?
2. what benefits / disadvantages of cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin over maven-failsafe-plugin  parallel execution ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the answer

"A common approach for running Cucumber features in parallel is to create a suite of Cucumber runners, one for each suite of tests you wish to run in parallel. For maximum parallelism, there should be a runner per feature file.
This is a pain to maintain and not very DRY."

https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin/issues/139

additional details -

..Despite its name cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin does not run any tests, it just automatically generates the Cucumber runners for you. This saves you time from making empty runner files and also just by changing the config of the cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin you can have brand new set of runner files..

copied from http://automationrhapsody.com/running-cucumber-tests-in-parallel/#comment-3455579028