# How to run all the Cucumber Feature files in parallel

Tags: spring-boot, maven-plugin, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have a bunch of feature files(around 15) where each feature file has a thread that needs to sleep for atleast 3 mins (for some complex background app to execute some functions). I need a way to execute all of them in parallel.

I have a simple CucumberRunnerTestCLass.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/java/com/sample/demo/features",glue{""}, plugin = {"pretty","html:target/cucumber"}, tags = {"@integrationTesting"})
public class JUnitRunnerTest {
}
```

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run my cucumber-jvm features in parallel? (with maven using cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539248/how-do-i-run-my-cucumber-jvm-features-in-parallel-with-maven-using-cucumber-jv)

Answer (score 0):

Provide threads like:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(threads=5,features = "src/test/java/com/sample/demo/features",glue{""}, plugin = {"pretty","html:target/cucumber"}, tags = {"@integrationTesting"})
public class JUnitRunnerTest {
}
```